# php strpos always returning false

Tags: php, twilio, strpos

I'm attempting to determine if a user sent a text message containing a certain string.

I'm having a strange issue with `strpos` always returning false, unless the needle parameter of the `strpos` function is hardcoded as a string, i.e. `"Sam"`.  I'm fetching the value for the desired needle variable via `mysqli_fetchassoc`, and comparing it to the text message body retrieved from `$_REQUEST['Body']`.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult))
    {           
        if (mysqli_num_rows($queryResult) > 1)
        {
            //$_REQUEST['Body'] is the body of the incoming text message that Twilio will process
            $messageBody= $_REQUEST['Body'];
            $recName = $row['rFName'];
            $recId = $row['recipientID'];



            if (strpos($messageBody, $recName) !== false)
            ...
```

If I hardcode the needle parameter as a string, like below, then it works fine.

```
 //This works
           if (strpos($messageBody, "Sam") !== false)
            ...
```

I've done a type check on both of the comparison values and ensured they are strings.  I must be missing something simple here.

Comment: Verify that $recName is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

Strpos pays attention to whitespace, go figure.  In my scenario, I had a space at the end of my test string, that looked like this: `Sam`.(An added space at the end of Sam)  Be sure to check for any stray whitespace in your string if you have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check the encoding of both strings being compared with [`mb_detect_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php), as `strpos` can have [issues comparing UTF-8 and ASCII strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#118905). Specifically:

```
# Now, encoding the string "Fábio" to utf8, we get some "unexpected" outputs.
# Every letter that is no in regular ASCII table, will use 4 positions(bytes).
# The starting point remains like before.
# We cant find the characted, because the haystack string is now encoded.

var_dump(strpos(utf8_encode("Fábio"), 'á'));
#bool(false)
```

Comment: Thanks.  As it turns out though, there was whitespace at the end of the needle parameter that strpos didn't ignore.  So, it was searching for `"Sam "` instead of `"Sam"`.